# PHP - Reorganize Query String Parameters

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have a query string like this:

```
?foo1bar1=a&foo1bar2=b&foo1bar3=c&foo2bar1=d&cats1dogs1=z
```

The parameters in this string could be arbitrary, and could have any number of indexes (so you could have just `foo=`, you could have `foo1bar1=` or something like `foo1bar1baz1=`. However, the parameters and their relevant indexes will be known ahead of time.

I'd like to be able to take this query string, plus a configuration, and re-structure it... The configuration might look something like this:

```
$indexes = array('foodex', 'bardex');
$columns = array('foo<foodex>bar<bardex>', 'cats<foodex>dogs<bardex>');
```

And the desired output would be the "columns" reorganized into rows indexed by the appropriate indexes, ready for storing in database rows. Something like this...

```
array(
    array(
        'foodex' => 1,
        'bardex' => 1,
        'foo<foodex>bar<bardex>' => 'a',
        'cats<foodex>dogs<bardex>' => 'z'
    ),
    array(
        'foodex' => 1,
        'bardex' => 2,
        'foo<foodex>bar<bardex>' => 'b',
        'cats<foodex>dogs<bardex>' => null
    ),
    etc.
)
```

I've thought of a couple ideas for solving this problem, but nothing seems terribly elegant... I could:

1. Write a recursive function that loops through all possible values of a known index, and then calls itself to loop through all possible values of the next known index, then records the results. This would be super slow... you might loop through thousands or millions of possible index values only to find a handful in the query string.
2. Loop through each actual value in the query string, do some sort of regex check to see if it matches one of the columns I'm looking for including wildcards for each index that's listed within it. Then I could build some sort of multi-dimensional array using the indexes and eventually flatten it for the output. This would run much faster, but seems awfully complex.

Is there an elegant solution staring me in the face? I'd love to hear suggestions.

Comment: So you want to store URL queries in SQL database? What is `foo<foodex>bar<bardex>`? What are you trying to do? Can you please explain your goal? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/237701) for reference.

Comment: I want to store query string parameters in a SQL database, but that's trivial. The question here is about restructuring the data. Given a bunch of parameters that could be multiple instances of the same parameter (`foo1=abc`, `foo2=def`), I want to generate one row for each value of the index, and put the parameter in the columns. Even that's not so bad, except that I need to be able to accept arbitrary numbers of indexes. So you could have a parameter with 3 indexes (`foo1bar1baz1=abc`) or even more...

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://uri.thephpleague.com/components/query/#array-representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is quick sample you can start with:

```
// your configuration
$indexes = array ('foodex', 'bardex');
$columns = array ('foo<foodex>bar<bardex>', 'cats<foodex>dogs<bardex>');

// column names converted into regexps
$columns_re = array_map ( function ($v) {
    global $indexes;
    return '/^' . str_replace ( array_map ( function ($v) {
        return '<' . $v . '>';
    }, $indexes ), '(\d+)', $v ) . '$/';
}, $columns );

// output array
$array = array ();
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
    foreach ( $columns_re as $reIdx => $re ) {
        $matches = array ();
        if (preg_match_all ( $re, $key, $matches )) {
            // generate unique row id as combination of all indexes
            $rowIdx = '';
            foreach ( $indexes as $i => $idxName )
                $rowIdx .= $matches [$i + 1] [0] . '_';
            // fill output row with default values
            if (! isset ( $array [$rowIdx] )) {
                $array [$rowIdx] = array ();
                foreach ( $indexes as $i => $idxName )
                    $array [$rowIdx] [$idxName] = $matches [$i + 1] [0];
                foreach ( $columns as $name )
                    $array [$rowIdx] [$name] = null;
            }
            // fill actually found value
            $array [$rowIdx] [$columns [$reIdx]] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

tested with php 5.3, with some modifications can be run under any version

Comment: So, basically option 2. Thanks! Somewhat comforting to know there wasn't a far easier algorithm staring me in the face.

Comment: Gonna go ahead and accept this since it answers the question, and nobody else has provided a suggestion for a better algorithm. Thanks!